# ModelMapper configuration

Tags: java, modelmapper

Am seeing behaviour I can't explain with `ModelMapper` whilst trying to map a boolean to char.

(I have checked, and the problem isn't [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) related).

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Entity { private boolean instance; }
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Item { private char instance; }

public final class ModelMapperTest
{
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Entity, Item>()
        {
            protected void configure()
            {
                map().setInstance(source.isInstance() ? 'Y' : 'N');
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void map()
    {
        for (final Item item : map(new ArrayList<Entity>()
        {
            {
                this.add(new Entity(true));
                this.add(new Entity(false));
            }
        }))
        {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    public List<Item> map(final List<Entity> entities)
    {
        return modelMapper.map(entities, new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

Which produces characters 't' and 'f' not 'Y' and 'N' as I'd intended.

> Item(instance=t)
>
> Item(instance=f)

Anyone know how the `ModelMapper` configuration should look?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a converter to map a boolean to char like this:

```
Converter<boolean, char> toChar = new AbstractConverter<boolean, char>() {
  protected char convert(boolean source) {
    return source ? 'Y' : 'N;
  }
};
```

Then your ProperyMap should use this converter to map it as below:

```
    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Entity, Item>()
        {
            protected void configure()
            {
                using(toChar).map().setIsInstance(source.isInstance());
            }
        });
    }
```

Take a look here:

- [ModelMapper.org - Converters](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#converters)
- [Java Code Example for Property Maps (examples with converters)](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.modelmapper.PropertyMap)

Comment: Ok, thanks @Pau, am pretty sure that would work (have written converters before) but fairly astonished ModelMapper doesn't handle this better out-the-box. Cheers anyway. Andrew

Comment: ;) I agree. I'm not pretty sure if it is the best solution but sometimes I'm also astonished with some kind of mappings..(maybe I need to understand better the library) anyway, it is a great library.